# Pandas: Convert column of dataframe from list to string and the string to have only unique values of list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

| Name | String Names |
| --- | --- |
| First | ['A','A','B','C'] |
| Second | ['AA','BB'] |

I want the output to be like

| Name | String Names |
| --- | --- |
| First | 'A','B','C' |
| Second | 'AA','BB' |

I need the list to be converted to str . I've done that using the below code

```
df['String Names'] = df['String Names'].str.join(',')
```

But I'm unable to get only the unique values.

Any suggestion how I can do it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order is not important convert values to sets:

```
df['String Names'] = df['String Names'].apply(set).str.join(',')
```

If order and performance is important use `dict` trick for remove duplicates:

```
df['String Names'] = df['String Names'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()))
```

---

```
df['String Names1'] = df['String Names'].apply(set).str.join(',')
df['String Names2'] = df['String Names'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()))
print(df)

     Name  String Names String Names1 String Names2
0   First  [A, A, B, C]         B,A,C         A,B,C
1  Second      [AA, BB]         AA,BB         AA,BB
```

Answer (score 1):

You might harness [pandas.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) function following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['First','Second'],'String Names':[['A','A','B','C'],['AA','BB']]})
df['String Names'] = df['String Names'].apply(pd.unique).str.join(',')
print(df)
```

output:

```
     Name String Names
0   First        A,B,C
1  Second        AA,BB
```

`pandas.unique` does preserve order.